# Window.load works only after browser tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using flex slider with multiple instance, the first slider works fine, but other slides are only showing correctly after changed browser tab and get back, but second slide's thumbnails show after only changed browser tab again.

How can I make them work same time, I mean they should be working when page loads first time.

Here is my code

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            // The slider being synced must be initialized first
            $('#carousel').flexslider({
                animation : "slide",
                controlNav : false,
                animationLoop : false,
                slideshow : false,
                itemWidth : 220,
                itemMargin : 5,
                asNavFor : '#slider'
            });

            $('#slider').flexslider({
                animation : "slide",
                controlNav : false,
                animationLoop : false,
                slideshow : false,
                sync : "#carousel"
            });

            $('#slider2').flexslider({
                animation : "slide",
                controlNav : false,
                animationLoop : false,
                slideshow : false
            });
            $('#carousel2').flexslider({
                animation : "slide",
                controlNav : false,
                animationLoop : false,
                slideshow : false,
                itemWidth : 220,
                itemMargin : 5,
                asNavFor : '#slider2'
            });
</script>
<html>
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg"
                                            style="height: 580px;" /></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div id="carousel" class="flexslider flex_carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel_icon"></div>
                                    <ul class="slides pull-left">
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <li><img
                                            src="assets/FlexSlider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg"
                                            style="height: 80px;" /></li>
                                        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
</html>
```

************* EDITED **************
You can see it online here http://goo.gl/cHMaBq
First tab (one star) works perfect.
There is no image on second tab, please go to another browser tab and return , you will see the slider works, but no thumbnail. Please go to another browser tab again and return, thumbnails will be shown.
Thanks

Comment: Any chance of adding a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please take a look at this http://goo.gl/cHMaBq Also I've edited my question

Comment: This is not a jsfiddle illustrating the problem so we'd really just be guessing and since the containing page has lots of other code it is hard (also a a non-trivial amount of effort) to isolate the problem.  Without you making the effort to make it easy I doubt you'll find an answer quickly here.

Comment: Sorry I tried, but elements weren't showing how it supposed to show on jsfiddle. Anyway thanks, I've fixed it : )

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it, pictures were rendered, but don't show until I resize browser.
So , this problem has been fixed this issue.

```
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function() {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                }, 0);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                }, 2)
            });
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.